# Solving $(2^k-3)b^2 - (2^{k+1}+1)ab - (2^k+2)a^2 = 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, vieta-jumping

I’m trying to solve the Diophantine equation
\begin{align} \tag{$\star$}
 (2^k-3)b^2 - (2^{k+1}+1)ab - (2^k+2)a^2 = 0,
\end{align}
where $k$ is a positive integer, and $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers (not necessarily positive). A computer search turns up only the solutions $k=1$ and $k=4$, with no more solutions $1 \le k \le 100$.

I had hoped that I could use Vieta-jumping to solve it, but after much trying and many sheets of sketch paper, I haven’t found the magic incantation. Any help — either with a Vieta-jumping hint, or with any hints toward a proof mechanism — would be greatly appreciated.

In case it helps, I know that
$$
  (b^2-2ab-a^2) \mid 2 \cdot 23.
$$
Also, it is trivial to show that ($\star$) implies $2^{2k+3}=c^2+23$ for some integer $c$.

Comment: It has an integer solution if and only if the discriminant is a square

Comment: Yes (cf. my edit of 11 minutes ago). The question then is, can ($\star$) be attacked in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor variant of Ramanujan Nagell. I would imagine a complete resolution is available somewhere.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   8
    1   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -8
    -1   3

  3^2 - 8 1^2 = 1

 x^2 - 8 y^2 = -23

Mon Aug 22 18:00:32 PDT 2016

x:  3  y:  2 ratio: 1.5  SEED   KEEP +-   y =   2
x:  7  y:  3 ratio: 2.33333  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -3 ,  2  y =   3
x:  25  y:  9 ratio: 2.77778  y =   3^2
x:  45  y:  16 ratio: 2.8125  y =   2^4
x:  147  y:  52 ratio: 2.82692  y =   2^2 13
x:  263  y:  93 ratio: 2.82796  y =   3 31
x:  857  y:  303 ratio: 2.82838  y =   3 101
x:  1533  y:  542 ratio: 2.82841  y =   2 271
x:  4995  y:  1766 ratio: 2.82843  y =   2 883
x:  8935  y:  3159 ratio: 2.82843  y =   3^5 13
x:  29113  y:  10293 ratio: 2.82843  y =   3 47 73
x:  52077  y:  18412 ratio: 2.82843  y =   2^2 4603
x:  169683  y:  59992 ratio: 2.82843  y =   2^3 7499
x:  303527  y:  107313 ratio: 2.82843  y =   3 35771
x:  988985  y:  349659 ratio: 2.82843  y =   3^2 38851
x:  1769085  y:  625466 ratio: 2.82843  y =   2 277 1129
x:  5764227  y:  2037962 ratio: 2.82843  y =   2 1018981
x:  10310983  y:  3645483 ratio: 2.82843  y =   3 1215161
x:  33596377  y:  11878113 ratio: 2.82843  y =   3 13 151 2017
x:  60096813  y:  21247432 ratio: 2.82843  y =   2^3 2655929

Mon Aug 22 18:02:32 PDT 2016

 x^2 - 8 y^2 = -23

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Based on your observation, I found Apery's theorem that equations of the form $$x^2+D=2^n$$ have at most two solutions. I'll look at that to see what I can see. Still going to try to solve ($\star$) directly/independently, though… because, based on my derivation, an effective attack could be applied to a lot more equations than just the Ramanujan-Nagell type.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan  $x^2 + 7 = 2^n$ has about five solutions, so Apery's theorem cannot be quite what you wrote.

Comment: Yes, $D=7$ is the single exception (q.v. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation#Equations_of_Ramanujan.E2.80.93Nagell_type).

Comment: @KierenMacMillan this http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~saradha/saradharev.pdf says $x^2 + 23 = 2^n$ has the ones we know along with $45^2 + 23 = 2048 = 2^{11}$ I see, that is my $y=16.$